# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Tags: jquery, opencart, javascript

Имеется скрипт для скролла:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // сохраняем высоту шапки
  var headerHeight = $('.menu-wrap').height();

  // прокрутка при клике по пункту меню 
  $("a.menu-nav-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // вычисляем смещение от начала документа до нужного раздела
    var offsetTop = $("#"+$(this).data("target")).offset().top - headerHeight;
    // производим прокрутку
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 500);
  });
  // обработка скроллинга (изменение активного элемента меню)
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var offsets = [];
    $('nav a').each(function(index, element){
      // собираем в массиве offsets смещения разделов относительно начала документа
      offsets.push($("#" + $(element).data('target')).offset().top);
    });
    // дополняем массив еще одним елементом- высота всего документа
    offsets.push($(document).height());
    // изменяем активный пункт как только область зашла за полэкрана: $(window).height() / 2
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop() + headerHeight + $(window).height() / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < offsets.length - 1; i++) {
      if (docScroll >= offsets[i] && docScroll < offsets[i+1]) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
        break;
      };
    };
  });
})
```

Если его подключаю, то в консоле хрома вылазят следующие ошибки:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null | scrolling.js:18
(anonymous function) |  scrolling.js:18
e.extend.each  |  jquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.each  |  jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function)  |  scrolling.js:16
f.event.dispatch  |  jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i   |  jquery.min.js:3
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело? В данной области не силён, рассчитываю на Вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: @w3bmak3r, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @w3bmak3r, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Ответ есть тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined. Но думаю, что уже не актуально.

Comment: Ответ есть тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined. Но думаю, что уже не актуально.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> offsets.push($("#" + $(element).data('target')).offset().top);
> ```

`$("#" + $(element).data('target'))` - это пустой набор, т. е. элемента с каким-то id не существует. `offset()` возвращает `null`, у которого, естественно, нет свойства `top`.

Ставь точку останова и дебажь. Или даже порсто включи автоостановку на ошибках.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
```

Похоже, что ты пытаешься использовать метод `'top'` для элемента, который на момент вызова не определен. Проверить это можно, поставив перед каждым вызовом `'top'` консоль лог с элементом, для которого ты его вызываешь. Если проблема в чем-то другом, то закинь свой код в песочницу и скинь сюда ссылку на него.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что

```
$(element).data('target') == undefined
```

Что влечёт за собой `$("#" + "underfined").offset().top`, элемента с таким идентификатором у вас нету, и как следствие метод `"top"` выдаёт ошибку.